# classList.add() does not work inside setTimeout() function

Tags: javascript, css, intersection-observer

I am using Intersection Observer to hide a div element when it is inside the viewport. For that purpose I am using setTimeOut() function to hide the div element after 2 seconds and using a nice CSS transition, but the classList.add() function does not seem to work inside the setTimeout() function in order to call the CSS transition to hide it.

This is my HTML where you can see the div element with id='sbox'.
All sections have a height of 100vh.

```
  <body>
    <section id="page-1" class="primera"></section>

    <section id="page-2" class="segunda"></section>

    <section id="page-3" class="tercera">
      <div id="sbox" class="small-box"></div>
    </section>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
```

this is my CSS:

```
.primera{
width: 100%;
height 100vh
}

.segunda {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #cbf3f0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cbf3f0, #2ec4b6);
}

.tercera {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #5e60ce;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  .small-box {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #ffbf69;
    transition: all 5s ease-out;
  }
}

.hide {
  transition: all 5s ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

This is my JS file:

```
let options = {
  root: null,
  threshold: 0.8,
};

function hideBox(entryArray) {
  let ibox = document.getElementById("sbox");

  if (entryArray[0].isIntersecting) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("hiding the first loading element");
      ibox.classList.add("hide");
    }, 2000);
  } else {
    ibox.classList.remove("hide");
  }
}

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(hideBox, options);
observer.observe(document.getElementById("page-3"));
```

Comment: `.tercera .small-box` has a higher CSS specificity than `.hide` - therefore the opacity in `.hide` is ignored

Comment: I tried using the observer.observe element as .small-box instead of page-3, but it does not seem to work either

Comment: The issue is with CSS specificity - nothing to do with your observer code. it also has nothing to so with being inside `setTimeout`

Comment: Perfect, it is solved! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `.tercera .small-box` has a higher [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than `.hide`, the opacity in `.hide` is ignored

Simplest solution is to add

add

```
&.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

inside `.small-box`

see the snippet

```js
let ibox = document.getElementById("sbox");

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("hiding the first loading element");
  ibox.classList.add("hide");
}, 2000);
```

```css
.primera {
  width: 100%;
  height 3em;
}

.segunda {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: #cbf3f0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cbf3f0, #2ec4b6);
}

.tercera {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: #5e60ce;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  .small-box {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #ffbf69;
    transition: all 5s ease-out;
    &.hide {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="page-1" class="primera"></section>

<section id="page-2" class="segunda"></section>

<section id="page-3" class="tercera">
  <div id="sbox" class="small-box">a</div>
</section>
```